# How does refocusing in a dual lens work?

Tags: focus, computational-photography

HTC One (M8) and the recent Huawei P9 offer dual lenses. This allows the option of refocussing after the picture has been clicked. Could someone explain how does that happen? How does the software combine the photos from the two sensors (one RGB and the other monochrome, in case of Huawei P9) to allow for the refocussing?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the HTC dual lenses is to create a "depth map". The distance between the camera and the objects in the picture is computed : each pixel has a distance associated. The following example (from http://www.i-art3d.com/Eng/About_Depth.htm) shows a depth map :

[image: example of depth map]

Knowing this, an algorithm can recreate artificial "depth of field" effect, emulating a picture taken with a given aperture, (re)focused where the user wants it.

Contrary to other brand, HTC doesn't take multiple pictures with various settings but a unique image, probably with a small aperture.